# Regex to Finite Automata

Tags: regex, finite-automata

How can I convert a regular expression such as:

`((e|£|\$)([1-9][0-9]*|0)(,|\$|\.){1}([0-9][0-9]))|(([1-9][0-9]*|0),[0-9][0-9](EUR))|([1-9][0-9]*|0)\$[0-9]{2}`

to a finite automata like this:

[image: finite automata like this]

Comment: Are you asking how to create the diagram, or compile it into a state table?

Comment: @Barmar I want the diagram, but if there is any way to create a state table and then get the diagram (using something like graphviz) I can take it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this online tool https://regexper.com/ which will automatically generate [diagram](https://regexper.com/#%28%28e%7C%C2%A3%7C%5C%24%29%28%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*%7C0%29%28%2C%7C%5C%24%7C%5C.%29%7B1%7D%28%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%29%29%7C%28%28%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*%7C0%29%2C%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%28EUR%29%29%7C%28%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*%7C0%29%5C%24%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D)

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, although it is very useful, I wan't that specific diagram type.

Comment: @RafaelMoreira: This diagram is almost the diagram you need. All you need to do is add explicit transitions in the place of the `one of`s and add states for every branch. (Then run the NFA-to-DFA algorithm on the result if you need a DFA instead of an NFA.)

Answer (score 1):

I won't go through the details but the process might look like this:

1. Rewrite your regex as a fully-parenthesized formal regular expression. If your regex has no equivalent fully parenthesized formal regular expression, stop; there is no finite automaton.
2. Use the standard constructive algorithm for proving finite automata are as powerful as (formal) regular expressions to construct a nondeterministic finite automaton which accepts the language described by the (formal) regular expression obtained in step 1.
3. Optional: determinize the nondeterministic finite automaton obtained in step 2 using e.g. the subset/powerset constructive algorithm used to show deterministic finite automata are as powerful as nondeterministic ones.
4. Optional: minimize the deterministic finite automaton obtained in step 3 using some standard DFA minimization algorithm.